# How do you use Open GL ES 2.0 (shaders) for video processing?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

This question is about iOS. On Android, it is very easy to use OpenGL ES 2.0 to render a texture on a view (for previewing) or to send it to an encoder (for file writing). I haven't been able to find any tutorial on iOS to achieve video playback (previewing video effect from a file) and video recording (saving a video with an effect) with shader effects. Is this something possible with iOS?

I've come across a demo about shaders called [GLCameraRipple](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html) but I have no clue about how to use it more generically. Ex: With `AVFoundation`.

[EDIT]

I trampled on [this tutorial about OpenGL ES, AVFoundation and video merging on iOS](http://tuohuang.info/video-merging-avfoundation-opengl-es-on-ios-intro) while searching for a snippet. That's another interesting entry door.

Comment: you might want to check out Brad Larsons GPUImage, open source app that you might learn from.  https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: I want to use it at last resort. I'm using Xamarin, so I rely on auto-generated API bindings that are incomplete / not all working well.  And I think that if what I'm trying to do is achievable, it should stand in a short page of code, not in an whole library. I might port it to Mono, but I was searching for a short term solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all very low-level stuff over in iOS land, with a whole bunch of pieces to connect.

The main thing you're likely to be interested in is [`CVOpenGLESTextureCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreVideo/Reference/CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef/). As the CV prefix implies, it's part of Core Video, in this case its primary point of interest is `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` which "creates a live binding between the image buffer and the underlying texture object". The documentation further provides you with explicit advice on use of such an image as a `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT` — i.e. the texture ID returned is usable both as a source and as a destination for OpenGL.

The bound image buffer will be tied to a [`CVImageBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVImageBufferRef), one type of which is a [`CVPixelBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelBufferRef). You can supply pixel buffers to an [`AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor_Class/index.html) wired to an [`AVAssetWriter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/index.html) in order to output to a video.

In the other direction, an [`AVAssetReaderOutput`](http://AVAssetReaderOutput) attached to a [`AVAssetReader`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetReader_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAssetReader/addOutput:) will vend [`CMSampleBuffer`s](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMSampleBuffer/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMSampleBufferRef) which can be queried for attached image buffers (if you've got video coming in and not just audio, there'll be some) that can then be mapped into OpenGL via a texture cache.

Comment: Thanks! The destination is far, but the indications are clear.